# Disabling App Transport Security and potential down-level client breaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security, secure-transport

In my current application I’ve disabled the [App Transport Security (ATS)](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33), by making the flag **Allow Arbitrary Loads** as YES.
Now I'm adopting ATS i.e latest version of my application will be adopted ATS.

My Question is for the users who are having my old version application will work after end of this year ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as apple mandating ATS by end of this year.

Comment: `Allow Arbitrary Loads` as `YES`?

Comment: You can disable ATS as long as you provide justification as to why you need to in your review notes. An existing app with ATS disabled will continue to function; this is set by your info.plist in your app, it isn't something Apple controls centrally.

Answer (score 2):

If your app does not have a specific reason, you may risk rejection:

Setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true will allow it to work, but Apple was very clear in that they intend to reject apps who use this flag without a specific reason. The main reason to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` I can think of would be user created content (link sharing, custom web browser, etc). And in this case, Apple still expects you to include exceptions that enforce the ATS for the URLs you are in control of.

If you do need access to specific URLs that are not served over TLS 1.2, you need to write specific exceptions for those domains, not use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES`. You can find more info in the [`NSURLSesssion` WWDC session](http://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/711/).

Please be careful in sharing the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` solution. It is not the recommended fix from Apple.